# Select left outer join value if it exists with LIMIT 1, else another value

Tags: mysql, sql

If a left outer join provides a value (t2.id for my example), I would like to select it.  Note that for my particular data, the left join will only have one or zero matches.  If not, I would like to select another value.

The following will not work because my query without the `LIMIT 1` might return multiple rows and the first might happen not to be one where the left join matched.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.id,t1.id) AS id
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.id=t1.t2_id
WHERE t2.fk=123
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

How can I select the value returned by a left join where a limit exists?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `INNER JOIN` instead?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan.  No, still need results if t2 doesn't match t1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `order by` to:

```
order by (t2.id is not null) desc
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon,  I will try it out when I get home.  If the outer join doesn't match, will I still get results?  Guess I will find out soon.

Comment: @user1032531 . . . Yes, you will still get results.  The outer join will return rows in the first table, even when there is no match.